# Cython: how to resolve TypeError: Cannot convert memoryviewslice to numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, cython

Inside a random_stuff_printer.pyx file, I have a `cdef` function that looks something like this:

```
cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=4] randomizer():
    return np.random.random((4, 4, 4, 4))
```

Then I have a `def` function that looks like this, inside the same random_stuff_printer.pyx:

```
def random_printer():
    random_stuff = randomizer()
    print random_stuff
```

I compile the file, and call random_printer, but I get the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot convert random_stuff_printer._memoryviewslice to numpy.ndarray`

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this is an issue of keeping your `def`, `cdef`s, and `cimport` and `import`s straight. Here's some code that works for me:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as cnp

cdef cnp.ndarray[cnp.float64_t, ndim=4] randomizer():    
    return np.random.random((4, 4, 4, 4))

def random_printer():
    cdef foo = randomizer()
    print(foo)
```

See for example this notebook: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/arokem/6fa00ceb17e16c367c8a

Comment: Hi arokem -- I want to thank you in advance. I haven't had a chance to try out your suggestion yet, but as soon as I do, I'll report back with how this worked out.

Comment: Why do you use `cdef foo = ...` instead of just `foo = ...`? I recognize that

Comment: For clarity, I removed the typo comment. As for the question. I think that cython needs to see a `cdef` here because the thing returning is not a regular np array, but a c-level object.

Comment: sadly, in my more complicated usecase, I still get the error even after clarifying np vs. cnp, and using cdef where I was getting the error initially...

Comment: I am not sure I follow: to you get the same error when using the code that I provided in the example and in the notebook linked?

Comment: Note: I can run the example above perfectly fine without differentiating between `cdef` and `def`. It might depend on the cython version or so, I have '0.29.14'.

So in the jupyter notebook, it would be: `import numpy as np` and `cimport numpy as np` and replacing `cdef cnp.ndarray[...]` by `cdef np.ndarray[...]` etc.